# emacs auto-complete-mode not work

Tags: auto-complete-mode, emacs23

1.I downloads package from this: https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete

2. Type: M-x load-file RET ~/auto-complete-master/etc/install.el RET
3. install to: ~/.emacs.d/ RET

Installation Result show:

> Successfully installed!
>
> Add the following code to your .emacs:
>
> (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")
> (require 'auto-complete-config)
>
> (ac-config-default)

However, I don't see characters AC in mode-line. I type:
M-x auto-complete-mode, but it show: [No match]

What problem with my emacs?
(GNU Emacs 23, Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Did you add that code to your `.emacs` and then restarted Emacs?

Comment: Have you tried disabling other modes you might be running to identify conflicts with auto-complete?  In my experience, auto-complete is incompatible with many other modes.

Comment: when I type M-x auto- TAB, in *Completions* buffer show:
> possible completions are:
> auto-composition-mode
> auto-fill-mode
> auto-insert-mode
> ... (many things)
but I don't see auto-complete-mode